# What would be the regular expression for date dd/06/2015,dd/mm/2015 for cypher query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What would be the regular expression for date dd/06/2015,dd/mm/2015 for cypher query in neo4j......

dd can be any date between 1 to 31 and month can be 1-12

I have a query with will search for a particular caller call count for whole month of June / for whole year of 2015

```
EX:
match(n:months_old) where n.caller = "9986519127" and n.callDate=****~'(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/06/2015'**** return count(*)
```

WHAT TO WRITE BETWEEN ****

Comment: You can also split on `/`  and compare the individual parts, is definitely more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
MATCH (n:months_old)
WHERE
  n.caller = "9986519127" AND
  n.callDate=~'(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/2015'
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you frequently query on date ranges, my suggestion would be to drop the regexp matching and use a more efficient structure such as a multi level index.

Fortunately, there's already a [TimeTree module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree) available from GraphAware to take care of the details (including auto attaching nodes) and provide you with an API/endpoint to query by date range.
More details: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to this module and work at GraphAware.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Luanne